# Docker один php composer и несколько версий php

Tags: php, composer, docker

Можно ли отдельно вынесенный контейнер с composer-ом, использовать в связке в разными версиями php(каждая версия со своими модулями в отдельном контейнере) ?

Comment: просто ставьте композер в каждом контейнере, это отлично автоматизируется

Comment: @Etki  Я думал сделать один контейнер с компосером и запускать его с разными php- контейнерами, я так понимаю на текущий момент так не получится сделать?
В идеале вообще запускать компосер с локальной машины, но при этом через интерпретатор php в контейнере (что-то типа удаленного интерпретатора)

Comment: Это можно сделать, но через дикие хаки с volume. Проще будет ставить внутрь php-контейнера, я не вижу никаких преград здесь

Comment: А как вы решаете проблему с  xdebug и компосером в одном контейнере ?

Comment: в третий раз: ставлю их внутрь